# wsdltojava error : java.lang.illegalArgumentException: the root package cannot be annoted

Tags: wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, illegalargumentexception

I am encountering the problem when trying to gen java code from wsdl using Apache CXF. I do it by run a command line. However, the command line showed an error:
wsdltojava error: java.lang.illegalArgumentException: the root package cannot be annoted
I've googled it for a long time, but no solution could be found!
Please help me!

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to show the WSDL (or a minimal WSDL which demonstrates the problem) and how you are invoking the `wsdl2java` tool.

Answer (score 0):

You must to  set the  "Package Name:" for your generated clases from wsdl.